# storing data in useState hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have an input tag for taking old and new password. I want to store it in a useState hook. How do I do that?
here is the code of the input tag:

```
<Form.Control
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Confirm new password"
                  name="checkPassword"
                  value={values.checkPassword}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
```

here is the useState hook:

```
 const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
```

Comment: Please put effort in understanding the React concepts. Read the documentation and React tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

1- change the `value` into `value={password}`

2- change the `onChange` into `onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}`

P.S. if your element is a standard HTML input with `e.target.value`. if not, you have to pass the correct argument to the `onChange` event.